# Hide A specific Admin Account From WordPress User List

Tags: php, wordpress, security, malware

I use the following code for hiding an admin user, but when I press save button in cPanel I get error message (BAILOUT malware detected).

```
function dt_pre_user_query($user_search) {
   global $current_user;
   $username = $current_user->user_login;

   if ($username != 'hiddenuser') {
      global $wpdb;
      $user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1',
         "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.user_login != 'hiddenuser'",$user_search->query_where);
   }
}
add_action('pre_user_query','dt_pre_user_query');
```

Comment: please share the return value of str_replace function's second argument, correct form should be "{$wpdb->users[0]->user_login} or something depending on what "$wpdb->users" is returning

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to completely HIDE a particular user from the User List, just add the following code at the top of the **functions.php** of your theme:

```
add_action('pre_user_query','site_pre_user_query');
function site_pre_user_query($user_search) {
  
    global $wpdb;
    $user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1',
      "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.user_login != 'admin'",$user_search->query_where);
  
}
```

replacing "admin" with the actual username that you would like to be hidden. Just tested it out and works like a charm.

Comment: This is not my answer, please go to the top and read again my question!

Comment: "I am sorry for that little misunderstanding. The "BAILOUT malware detected" is most probably returned by your host's anti-malware software that's in place. Since it is clearly a false-positive, I would strongly recommend you to consider of reaching your hosting provider to check the logs of their Firewall/Malware system in place and let you know what's going on. It would be also a good idea to initiate a scan of your entire account just to ensure that there are no malicious processes running and causing this.